# JSF - How to throw an exception when submit a button with condition rendered = false

Tags: jsf, rendered-attribute

I am working on a project on JSF2.0 
Here is my code

CountBean.java

```
    count = 1;
    function increase() {
         this.count++;
    }
    
    function decrease() {
         this.count--;
    }
```

count.xhtml

```
    <ui:Fragment rendered="#{countBean.count > 100}">
        <h:commandButton id="submit-button" value="increase" action="countBean.increase"/>
    </ui:Fragment>
    <ui:Fragment rendered="#{countBean.count > 0}">
        <h:commandButton id="submit-button" value="decrease" action="countBean.decrease"/>
    </ui:Fragment>
```

I run the application and open 2 tabs on Chrome 
tab1: 2 buttons increase and decrease is showed. Execute button "decrease" and then switch to tab2 
tab2: 2 buttons increase and decrease is showed. Execute button "decrease" 
On tab1, the function decrease is run 
When performing the submit button in tab2, the page is reloaded and only the increase button is displayed, the decrease function is not run

Instead of the page being reloaded, I want to throw an exception for handler, please help me 
Thanks for your support

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]